# eSATA port multiplier a85 chipset: Drives not recognized in my FM2A85X-ITX

Tags: linux, motherboard, bios, external-hard-drive, esata

I have a little probleme with the esata port of my motherboard.
i am under debian 8 with the 3.16.0-4 kernel.
i have upgrade the bios to the last known today ( 1.60)

and i have check in the internet this esata port have port multiplier 
http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/asrock-fm2a85x-itx-motherboard/

i have an icybox ICY BOX IB-3640SU3 with 3 hdd in there.

the thing is my linux can see just one hdd ans when i go in my bios i see just one hdd too ...

So my question is, despite what internet and not the constructor ( there is no information on the port multiplier ) says have you heard about port multiplier on the a85 chipset ?